# Prove that he didn’t/hadn’t

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses, conditionals

Let’s say someone interviewed someone else for a job, and the candidate thought about complaining about discrimination but eventually he didn’t.
Now the interviewer and a third party are talking about the situation.
Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two sentences?

> “If he had sued, you would have had to prove that you **didn’t discriminate** / **hadn’t discriminated** in order to not….”
> Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which tense to use here is a style choice.

The two versions technically have different meanings, but the difference is so trivial that it doesn't affect what someone would understand.

> If he had sued, you would have had to prove that you **didn't discriminate**.

In this version with *simple past*, the referring time is now, and the interview happened in the past, so it means **the interview happened before now**.

> If he had sued, you would have had to prove that you **hadn't discriminated**.

In this version with *past perfect*, the referring time is the imaginary time when the interviewee sued, which is in the past, so it means **the interview happened before the suing**.